# How do you define a block of code once to be used many times?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

By code block I mean:

```
def callBlock
  yield
  yield
end


callBlock { puts "In the block" } #this is the block
```

Comment: Check this post on how to use blocks http://www.jonathanspooner.com/web-development/ruby-5/how-does-a-ruby-block-work/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
b = lambda { puts "this is the block" }
callBlock &b
```

or

```
b.call
```

with arguments:

```
def call_block_name
    yield "Dave"
    yield "Mary"
    end

b = lambda { |s| puts "this is block #{s}" }
call_block_names &b
```

and

```
b.call("sam")
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `Proc.new` to capture a block, e.g.

```
def callBlocks(*args, &block)
  args.each { |arg| arg.call }
  block.call if block_given?
end

my_proc1 = Proc.new { puts "proc1" }
my_proc2 = Proc.new { puts "proc2" }

callBlocks(my_proc1, my_proc1, my_proc2) {
  puts "block"
}
```

produces:

```
proc1
proc1
proc2
block
```

Want some arguments with that?

```
def callBlocks(*args, &block)
  args.each { |arg| arg.call(1, 2, 3) }
  block.call(4, 5, 6) if block_given?
end

my_proc1 = Proc.new { |a, b, c| puts "proc1 with #{a}, #{b}, #{c}" }
my_proc2 = Proc.new { |a, *dummy| puts "proc2 only needs #{a}" }

callBlocks(my_proc1, my_proc1, my_proc2) { |*abc|
  puts "block with #{abc.join('/')}"
}
```

produces:

```
proc1 with 1, 2, 3
proc1 with 1, 2, 3
proc2 only needs 1
block with 4/5/6
```

Answer (score 1):

1. [Here is a screencast on how you use
   blocks in view](http://railscasts.com/episodes/40-blocks-in-view)
2. [This is another
   great block tutorial](http://www.igvita.com/2007/03/15/block-helpers-and-dry-views-in-rails/)